# Split mkv file with mkvtoolnix command line

Tags: macos, unix, movie, mkv

I found mkvtoolnix command line, installed with brew.
But i found nothing about splitting a movie with the command line, i only found with GUI.

The installation create 4 binary `mkvextract` `mkvinfo` `mkvmerge` `mkvpropedit` .

**SOLUTION :**

`mkvmerge --split 3G -o "film.mkv" ./mymkvfile`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Either use the command line `mkvmerge`with `--split` (see https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html)
or use the GUI on the "Global" tab ("Splitting").

For example, to split the file `movie.mkv` into 1.5GB chunks:

```
mkvmerge --split 1500M -o movie-split.mkv movie.mkv
```

Note that fractional split sizes aren't supported, so `--split 1.5G` won't work.

Comment: Thanks you, i use the command `mkvmerge --split 3G -o "film.mkv" ./mymkvfile`